Tensor product of sheaves locally isomorphic to constant sheaf is a constant sheaf
This is from Kashiwara's sheaves on manifolds exercise3.3:
Let $X$ be a topological space, $F$ a sheaf on X locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{X}$ (constant sheaf on X), then $F \otimes F \cong \mathbb{Z}_{X}$ is a canonical isommorphism.
My question is how to get the global natural morphism?
If for any open sbuset $U$ of $X$,the map $1 \mapsto id\otimes id$ induces morphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $F(U)\otimes F(U)$,can it gives a global morphism?
If this is right, then replacing $\mathbb{Z}$ to a unital commutative ring $A$, the conclusion also holds?
Thank you for your help!

What do you mean by $id \otimes id$? I'm not sure how to mean to interpret $id$ as an element of $F(U)$. Also, the value of $\mathbb{Z}_X$ on an open set $U$ is not necessarily $\mathbb{Z}$.

A quick remark since you already got Mark Saving's excellent answer, but if you are familiar with cohomology, you could also argue as follow : sheaves locally isomorphic to $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_X$ are classified with $H^1(X,\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_X^\times)$ (with the tensor product of sheaves corresponding to the group law on $H^1$) but $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_X^\times \simeq \underline{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}_X$ is 2-torsion, thus $H^1(X,\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_X^\times)$ is also 2-torsion and thus your result follow.

@diracdeltafunk
I'm sorry for my terrible statement. Maybe I want to consider this in the level of presheaf and use sheafification.

@Roland Thank you for your great method.

This is something specific to $\mathbb{Z}$. To illustrate what about $\mathbb{Z}$ is special, consider the case where $X$ is a 1-point space, so we are just working with ordinary $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (Abelian groups). Suppose $M$ is an Abelian group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Then there are two different isomorphisms, call them $f, -f : M \to \mathbb{Z}$. To see this, take some generator $g$ of $M$; $g$ can be sent either to $1$ or to $-1$, and this choice completely determines the isomorphism.
Now note that $f \otimes f = (-f) \otimes (-f) : M \otimes M \to \mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}$ by bilinearity. This means that regardless of which isomorphism $M \to \mathbb{Z}$ we pick, we get the same isomorphism $M \otimes M \to \mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}$. Composing with the canonical isomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}$ gives us a choice of isomorphism $M \otimes M \to \mathbb{Z}$ which doesn’t depend on the choice of isomorphism $M \to \mathbb{Z}$. This argument easily extends to the general sheaf case.
In general, if we are working with $R$-modules and we have some $M$ which is isomorphic to $R$, the family of $R$-module isomorphisms is of the form $\{u f \mid u \in R^\times\}$, where $f$ is some choice of $R$-module isomorphism $f : M \to R$ and $R^\times$ is the group of units of $R$. If $R^\times$ has the convenient property that $u^2 = 1$ for all $u$, then the argument we applied to $\mathbb{Z}$ works perfectly. Otherwise, we are not always able to make a global choice of isomorphism.
Consider a ring $R$ and a unit $u \in R^\times$. Let $X = \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ be the circle. Let $W_u = \{(r, x) \mid r \in R, x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and let $Y_u = W_u / \sim$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation $(r_1, x_1) \sim (r_2, x_2)$ if and only if $x_2 - x_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r_2 = r_1 u^{x_2 - x_1}$. For some intuition, think of $(r, x)$ as representing $r u^x$, although this isn’t at all rigorous. Then $Y_u$ is a topological space equipped with a covering space map $Y_u \to X$ whose fibers are $R$-modules in a continuous way, which gives rise to a locally constant sheaf $\mathcal{F}_u$ of $R$-modules on $X$.
It is not hard to show that $\mathcal{F}_u$ is a constant sheaf if and only if $u = 1$ by considering the monodromy (the action of the fundamental group of $X$ on the stalks of $\mathcal{F}_u$). Moreover, we see that $\mathcal{F}_u \otimes \mathcal{F}_v \cong \mathcal{F}_{uv}$, so in particular, $\mathcal{F}_u \otimes \mathcal{F}_u \cong \mathcal{F}_{u^2}$ is locally constant iff $u^2 = 1$. So in fact, this proposition about sheaves of $R$-modules only works when all units of $R$ square to 1.

Great answer. This also means that the question has nothing really to do with constant sheaf I guess. I mean that we can find a good generalization.

@MartinBrandenburg This appears correct. The result certainly follows for any sheaf of rings which has the unit-squaring property I mentioned. I suspect the converse will be something like the following: suppose $R$ is a sheaf of rings on $X$, and for all $f : Y \to X$, all locally finite free rank 1 $f^{-1}(R)$-modules $M$ satisfy $M \otimes M \cong f^{-1}(R)$. Then all units of $R$ square to 1. It’s possible we need to replace the quantifier over continuous maps with a quantifier over geometric morphisms or locale homomorphisms.

@ Mark Saving It is really excellent anwser and it eliminates my confusion perfectly. Thank you for your help!
